# Stage Tutorial Error: Laser Model Type Not Found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 1210
Nvidia GeForce GT640M
Groovy

Followed Tutorial in:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers

Successfully downloaded: http://mobotica.googlecode.com/files/stage_controllers.tar.gz
Successfully extracted
Successfully found by rospack find

Filesystem structure for stage_controller looks fine
But when I try to do: rosrun stage stageros /home/vmrguser/rosGWS/sandbox/stage_controllers/world/roomba-wander.world

Or any other world configuration, I get the following behavior:

- Stage simulation window opens and then closes
- Console says:
  err: Model type laser not found in model typetable (/tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-stage-1.6.7/debian/ros-groovy-stage/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)

Not sure why this happens

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58948/stage-tutorial-error:-laser-model-type-not-found/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2013-03-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on 2013-04-08**:
Hi, Have you solved the problem for using stage simulations, i have exactly the same problem, I am getting the following message

err: Model type laser not found in model typetable (/tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-stage-1.6.7/debian/ros-groovy-stage/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Groovy has Stage 4, which no longer provides the **laser** device simulation. It has been replaced by a generic [**ranger** simulation](http://rtv.github.com/Stage/group__model__ranger.html).

It looks like the ROS stage wiki page documentation is out of date.

Old world files need to be ported to the new interface.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [basbaum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4662/basbaum/) on 2013-04-11**:
how can one port an old world file to the new interface?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-11**:
You will have to consult the Stage documentation for that.